# How to re-enable an istream FIFO closed by the other end?

Tags: c++, iostream, fifo

I am receiving data within through a FIFO using an `istream`. Once the other end closes it, I am not able to be ready again although I cleared `eof` bit. The `badbit` is always there.

How to re-enable my FIFO in read mode?

Here's my code snippet:

```
std::istream &os;
// ...
try {
    os.get(tmp, length+1);
}
catch(std::exception const& e)
{
    std::cerr << "exception failure  caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
}

if ((os.rdstate() & std::ios_base::eofbit) > 0) {
    os.clear();
    os.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
}
```

Comment: How is it closed?

Comment: The process in the other end is killed when it does not use the fifo.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that the stream is not closed properly?

Comment: No, closing it properly on the other side has same effect.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was finally to replace std::ifstream with std::filebuf and close filebuf when istream is not available anymore

```
std::filebuf fb;
while (1==1)
    {
    if fb.open(myfifo, std::ios::binary|std::ios::in)
    {
    std::istream infifo(&fb);
    while (infifo)
    {
        infifo >> *tmp;
        // do your job
    }

    fb.close();
    }
```